# Roll your own Twillio like SMS?

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

How does Twillio get to send so many messages via SMS? I am thinking about making my own service for my company for internal use, but I am trying to discover how they managed to do that in such a large quantity while still remaning afloat? Are they using some sort of connection with a large set of phones, and automagically sending the messages from their actual devices? Wouldn't their service provider frown upon that kind of volume?

Comment: e.g. the German Telekom (provider) offers a [Global SMS API](http://www.developergarden.com/en/apis/apis-sdks/global-sms-api/) for developers – twilio could use a provider's service like the _Global SMS API_ Wikipedia tells you more about [SMS gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway)s

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does SMS gateways work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999272/how-does-sms-gateways-work)

Comment: You don't really need to use an API to send out texts for your company, you can just use a service like [Mobile Text Alerts](https://mobile-text-alerts.com) to manage and send out messages for you.

Answer (score 0):

They are at most using **SMPP protocol** to send SMS messages directly to their service. SMPP is a protocol widely used for sending mass (bulk) SMS messages between third-party and operator.

Excerpt from Wikipedia:

> The protocol is based on pairs of request/response PDUs (protocol data
>   units, or packets) exchanged over OSI layer 4 (TCP session or X.25
>   SVC3) connections. PDUs are binary encoded for efficiency. Data
>   exchange may be synchronous, where each peer waits for a response for
>   each PDU being sent, and asynchronous,

See full Wikipedia article: [Short Message Peer-to-Peer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Peer-to-Peer)